# Find and replace emoticon with the according smiley image

Tags: c#, regex, string, data-structures, replace

I have got a problem with my exercise. The input data is a set of sentences - `string[] sentences` - The exercise's requirement is that how to find and replace emoticon (ex: :D) to according smiley image in each sentences, and then export them to .html file.

File text data define emoticon and smiley has a structure like that:

`[imagename] tab [emoticon1] space [emoticon2] space [emoticon2]`

```
smile.gif    :) :-) :=) (smile)
sadsmile.gif :( :-( :=( (sad)
laugh.gif    :D :-D (laugh)
...
```

**The first issue** is which C#'s data structure to store emoticon and smiley.

`I'm happy :). How are you?` -> `I'm happy <img src="smile"> How are you?`

**The second issue** is how I code to search and replace emoticon.

**the last issue is**, because the export file is html format, so we must encode html, may be we use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(...)` But the resultSentence contain `<img ...>` tag, so I think it invole to the sencond issue...

Please help me to solve those above problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: TL;DR, but you need to at least `Regex.Escape()` your patterns before using them in a regular expression, or the regex metacharacters will foul up the match.

Comment: Thank Tim for your advice. Using RegularEx is just my opinion, I hesitate and I don't know if it's a good solution in this case. what is "TL;DR"?

Comment: Too long; didn't read. Three questions in one, and a lot of text to look at make this post (in my opinion) a less-than-optimal candidate for serious contemplation...

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker, too long ?! You must be kidding...

Comment: @Thomas: Did you see the question before the edit? It's much more concise now.

Comment: @Tim, sorry, I didn't realize it had been edited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to load the smiley "mappings" into a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> LoadSmileys(string fileName)
{
    var smileys = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(new[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (int i = 1; i < parts.Length; i++)
            {
                smileys[parts[i]] = parts[0];
            }
        }
    }
    return smileys;
}
```

Then, just loop over the keys, and replace each occurrence of the key with the corresponding image. To avoid the problem mentionned in your comment to Carra's answer, just replace the longest keys first:

```
StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder(originalText);
foreach (var key in smileys.Keys.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length))
{
    tmp.Replace(key, GetImageLink(smileys[key]));
}
```

Note the use of a `StringBuilder`, to avoid creating many instances of `String`.

It's obviously not the most efficient approach, but at least it's simple... you can always try to optimize it later if it turns out to be a performance  bottleneck.

---

UPDATE

OK, so there is still a problem if some of your smileys include reserved HTML characters like '<' or '>'... If you encode the text to HTML before replacing the smileys, these characters will be replaced with `&lt;` or `&gt;`, so the smileys won't be recognized. On the other hand, if you encode the text after replacing the smileys with `<img>` tags, the tags will be encoded as well.

Here's what you could do:

- assign a unique identifier to each smiley, something unlikely to appear in the original text, like a GUID
- replace each occurrence of each smiley by the corresponding identifier (again, starting with the longest smiley)
- encode the resulting text to HTML
- replace each occurrence of each smiley identifier by the appropriate `<img>` tag

  ```
  var mapping = LoadSmileys(@"D:\tmp\smileys.txt");
  var smileys = mapping.Keys.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length)
                       .ToArray();

  // Assign an ID like "{93e8b75a-6837-43f8-95ec-801ed59bc167}" to each smiley
  var ids = smileys.Select(key => Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B"))
                   .ToArray();

  string text = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\tmp\test_smileys.txt");

  // Replace each smiley with its id
  StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder(text);
  for (int i = 0; i < smileys.Length; i++)
  {
      tmp.Replace(smileys[i], ids[i]);
  }

  // Encode the text to HTML
  text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(tmp.ToString());

  // Replace each id with the appropriate <img> tag
  tmp = new StringBuilder(text);
  for (int i = 0; i < smileys.Length; i++)
  {
      string image = mapping[smileys[i]];
      tmp.Replace(ids[i], GetImageLink(image));
  }

  text = tmp.ToString();
  ```

Comment: Thank Thomas. The last issue is, I want to show the result to html page, so the string editedText (tmp) should be encode html before it's written to html file. But the edited text contain tag <img...> (ex: `I'm happy <img src="smile.gif"> How are you?`), if we encode whole of text, the tag <img..> also be encoded, so it will be show as string `<img src="smile.gif>` instead of image smile.gif on html page.

Comment: You just need to do the HTML encoding *before* you replace the smileys... Of course if you have smileys with characters like '<' or '>' it gets more complicated...

Comment: Yes, it gets more complicated so I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple string.replace here.

```
foreach(string text in sentences)
{
    foreach(var kvp in dict)
    {
      text = text.replace(kvp.Key, GetImageLink(kvp.Value));
    }
}
```

To create the html you're better of using the native C# classes like [HtmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx) or an XmlWriter.

Comment: Thank Carra, but I don't think it's simple like this. Considering about two emoticon :) and :)), if the sentence is "I'm laughing :))", the ":)" may be replace first instead of ":))", because the loop to retreive key in dictionary is not to order as when we add. And more problems appears with your solution, such as encoding text while it contain <img> tag...